# Github action zip doesn't find the files on self hosted worker

Tags: shell, zip, github-actions

I've been trying to archive files after compilation matching the wildcard `**/dist` when I look into my `_work` folder of my GitHub action worker, I see the files and if I run the zip command from shell, it works fine, but in action, it throws an error saying it can't find any files matching

```
zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -qq -r archive.zip . -i **/dist)
```

Yet when I run directly in the runner `ls -la **/dist` I get a list of over 200 files

I was also able to reproduce the issue by adding the command inside my `package.json` then when I run `yarn archive` I get the same issue as GitHub action

```
 "archive": "pwd && ls -la **/dist && zip -r **/dist",
```

Output of `yarn archive`

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ pwd && ls -la **/dist && zip -r **/dist
/home/mathieu_auclair/actions-runner/_work/server/server
ls: cannot access '**/dist': No such file or directory
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: I tried with ```sudo``` and still the same output, so probably not a permission or owner issue

Comment: I even added ```ls -la packages/wallet-rest-client/dist``` to my ```package.json```, and it worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is about how the shell will interpret the wildcards used.

I would try and put the set of commands  `ls -la **/dist && zip -r **/dist` in a bash executable script starting with  `#!/bin/bash`, and call said script instead of chaining commands with '`**`'.

The [OP MathieuAuclair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7253534/mathieuauclair) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73017262/github-action-zip-doesnt-find-the-files-on-self-hosted-worker/73017409?noredirect=1#comment128963412_73017409):

> Indeed, I was able to fix it by making the zip command specification more detailed, I guess it's compatible between both interpretations
>
> ```
> zip -r archive.zip . --include **/dist/**
> ```

Comment: Wow, nice catch! Indeed, I was able to fix it by making the zip command specification more detailed, I guess it's compatible between both interpretations, thanks for the help!
FYI full command used: ```zip -r archive.zip . --include **/dist/**```

Comment: @MathieuAuclair Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.